# Java multithreading - variable not updated

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm having some troubles with a variable while in a multi-threaded environment.

I have 3 components/threads: Controller, Handler, ExternalAgent.

Controller hands off raw data to Handler. Handler spins off a new ExternalAgent thread for further processing. ExternalAgent comes back to Handler once it's done doing its thing and adds messages to a linked list for further processing by the Handler.

The problem is, the messages added by the ExternalAgent are not visible to some methods inside the Handler. Here's the Handler code:

```
 public class InboundHandler implements InboundController.Handler {

    private Thread receiver;
    private volatile LinkedList<Message> bufferedMsgs = new LinkedList<Message>();
    private volatile boolean isAlive = true;

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);

    public InboundHandler() {
        receiver = new Thread(this,"receiver");
        receiver.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isAlive) {
            processBuffer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String msg) {
        Message packet = (Message) new Parser<Message>(Message.class,msg).getObject();
        new ExternalAgent(this,packet).start();

    }

    public void processBuffer() {
        logger.info("Processing buffersize .." + bufferedMsgs.size());

        synchronized (bufferedMsgs) {
            Iterator<Message> it = bufferedMsgs.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                //PROCESSING
            }
        }
    }

    public void addMsgToBuffer(Message m) {
        synchronized (bufferedMsgs) {
            bufferedMsgs.addLast(m);
        }
    }
```

**Controller** talks to **Handler** through the `process(msg)` interface
**ExternalAgent** talks to the **Handler** through the `addMsgToBuffer(msg)` interface.

In the method `processBuffer()`, the LinkedList bufferedMsgs always shows empty although if I print it in the method `addMsgToBuffer()`, it gives me the expected contents. I have tried everything in my knowledge to understand why this is happening but I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: The `bufferedMsgs` list isn't `static` which means that each instance of `InboundHandler` will have its own list, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: @Titus: but, we are not aware of the information that many instances of InboundHandler are getting created. Manoj: How are instances of InboundHandler getting created? Does controller create an instance of InboundHandler for each message it receives?

Comment: I thought `ExternalAgent` will create a new instance of `InboundHandler` so it can call the `addMsgToBuffer` but I see now that you pass the current `InboundHandler` instance in the `ExternalAgent` constructor.

Comment: There is only one instance of InboundHandler and one instance of Controller. There would be mulitple instances of ExternalAgent(s). Edit: Controller and Handler instances are created by an initializing Main function

Comment: You should move the `logger.info(...  bufferedMsgs.size());` inside the `synchronized` block because currently you're logging the list's size before other threads finish modifying it.

Comment: @Manoj: Could you add `logger.info("Processing buffersize .." + bufferedMsgs.size());` in a synchronized block within addMsgToBuffer() method, by doing this, we would come to know, while adding a message to the buffer, what is the size? If size is zero all the time, then I guess, multiple instances of Handlers are possible, as Titus mentioned above. If not, then we need to check other causes.

Comment: That was helpful. It showed size - 1 just the one time but that helped me track down an issue with the "processing" section inside the while loop below that was causing the overall failure in processing the buffer. Thanks